# Getting error non-void return value in void function | Swift

Tags: swift

I don't understand why I am getting the following error when executing this function:

> error: unexpected non-void return value in void function
> return [index, dic[value]!]

```
func findIndexes(_ nums: [Int], _ target: Int) -> [Int] {
    var dic = [Int:Int]()
    var answer: [Int] = []
    nums.enumerated().forEach { index, value in
        
        //the goal is to get the index of the value matching the difference
        //check if current value == anything in dictionary
        
        //MARK: Add the Index and Difference to Dictionary
        let difference = (target - value)
        if (dic.keys.contains(value) && !dic.values.contains(index)) {
            return [index, dic[value]!]
        }
        dic[difference] = index
    }
    return []
}

print(findIndexes([0,11,15,2,7], 9))
```

Comment: You don't get it when _executing_ anything. It's a _compile_ error.

Comment: You're correct, I was testing in playground which does not show compile errors until executing..what causes this error in my code? Array should be returned either empty or not, how is it written incorrectly.

Comment: Don't test in a playground. The error messages are not, by and large, useful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unclear what you're trying to do, but this is a version of what you *are* doing that compiles:

```
func findIndexes(_ nums: [Int], _ target: Int) -> [Int] {
    var dic = [Int:Int]()
    var answer: [Int] = []
    for (index, value) in nums.enumerated() {
        let difference = (target - value)
        if (dic.keys.contains(value) && !dic.values.contains(index)) {
            return [index, dic[value]!]
        }
        dic[difference] = index
    }
    return []
}
```

Why the difference? `for...in` is a loop. You can return from the surrounding function from within it, break out of it, etc. `forEach` loops *implicitly* but it is not a loop; it takes a *closure*, and you can't return out of that unless it's a closure that yields a return value, and this one doesn't; its type, as you can see from the docs, is `(Self.Element) throws -> Void` — and Void means "no return value".

If you insist on using `forEach`, you can do what you're trying to do with a bit of extra jiggery-pokery:

```
func findIndexes(_ nums: [Int], _ target: Int) -> [Int] {
    var dic = [Int:Int]()
    var answer: [Int] = []
    nums.enumerated().forEach { index, value in
        let difference = (target - value)
        if (dic.keys.contains(value) && !dic.values.contains(index)) {
            answer = [index, dic[value]!]
            return
        }
        dic[difference] = index
    }
    return answer
}
```

I *think* that does what you're trying to do, but I'm not sure; it seems unnecessarily obscure. In my personal opinion, the way to program is to Say What You Mean (SWYM).

Comment: The main difference I see is that I am using a trailing closure in a forEach and you are using a for loop..is have a return inside a closure wrong? Genuinely asking, I am currently learning

Comment: I've added further explanation in an edit to my answer. Basically you're correct!

Comment: I added a `forEach` variant that I _think_ gives the same result.

Comment: Just to clarify, the reason you were able to return inside `forEach` in your second response, was because you technically returned nothing which is still acceptable for a closure that yields no return value correct?

Comment: Exactly so. I passed the value out  by assignment instead of returning it.